# I need help creating a javascript popup on page load that closes when the parent window closes

Tags: javascript

First off, thanks for taking the time to check this out and provide assistance. This is a fantastic community.

Alright to my question...I need to create a popup that contains a music player when a site is loaded. Once the site is closed, it should close the popup window. This so far is some coe ive come up with, however I'm not that great at javascript. Right now I'm just trying to build the open close actions. I'll add the player later.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function load() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com','player','
    height='320,width=320,scrollbars,resizable'); 
  }
  function unload() {
    parent.player.close();
  }
window.onload = load;
window.onunload = unload;
</script>
```

This code does not work. I'm not sure why. What do I have to modify to make it function correctly?

Comment: It does not work. What do I have to modify to make it function correctly?

Comment: I'm using firebug to produce errors and it is not giving any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  var player;
  function load() {
   player = window.open('http://www.google.com','player','height=320,width=320,scrollbars,resizable'); 
  }
  function unload() {
      player.close();
  }
window.onload = load;
window.onunload = unload;
</script>
```

Comment: I have fixed one error, there was extra "'" after height, I have tested it in ff 5 and its working

Comment: Senad, so far so good. Only issue I'm running into is that when I use my navigation bar to switch a page, it closes then reopens the popup. I need the popup to stay open until the website is closed. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Thanks I'll make a new post :P